# OSPM - power management in OS

Tags: operating-system, cpu-usage

1. How does one increase or decrease the frequency scaling factor , or turn off frequecy scaling ?
2. how to turn ON or OFF cpuidle state ?
3. how to switch between tickless and non-tickless ?
4. how to make sense of the data obtained form commands like top , memstat, iostat, netstat etc
5. how to turn ON/OFF power management option ?
6. how to manipulate the cpu governors ?

Comment: That's a lot of questions - is that homework? I recommend splitting it into separate questions. You also need to indicate what operating system you use, and what CPU.

Comment: not homework :) I want to learn this stuff as I'm into a project that requires me to do these things. I request you to answer to question numbers 1, 2, 3 ,6. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. See Documentation/cpu-freq/core.txt in the Linux kernel source tree.
2. See Documentation/cpuidle/core.txt
3. Linux cmdline parameters "nohz=on" or "nohz=off".
4. See #1. In short: sysfs. There's a fair amount of stuff in that directory, actually.